# Spring Boot Actuator always enable shutdown EndPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building application based on Spring Boot.
I'm also adding the `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. According to [document here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints), the shutdown Endpoint is not enabled by default.

However it can be seen from JMX and can be executed to shutdown the application.

I've also tried to put

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=false
```

in the application.properties to disable it, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Where am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure? I'm more believe this is a bug. Even if the document is referring to accessing endpoints via HTTP, accessing via JMX should be consistent too.

Comment: No, sorry, you're correct. It looks like `EndpointMBeanExporter` is ignoring an endpoint's enabled property. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2873)

Comment: Thanks for opening an issue. I hope it will be addressed soon before my application go to production.